# Datalabels only showing the latest value plotted on the max value

Tags: typescript, vue.js, highcharts

I am plotting some values on the `yAxis.max` only issue with that is data label only shows for the latest value.

Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/stefadan83/uqyovdhr/2/
I would expect the values `950, 189, 145` to be visible instead only 145 is there.

I want all the values plotted on the max to have the label.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to update points inside `dataLabels.formatter` callback. Instead, update points in the `chart.load` event callback and save real value as an eg. `point.realValue`. Then inside `dataLabels.formatter` use it to show max values:

```
chart: {
  renderTo: 'container',
  type: 'line',
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var chart = this;

      chart.series.forEach(function(series) {
        series.points.forEach(function(point) {
          if (point.y > 100) {
            point.realValue = point.y;

            point.update({
              y: 100
            }, false, false);
          }
        });
      });

      chart.redraw(false);
    }
  }
}

...

plotOptions: {
  line: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function() {
        if (this.point.realValue > 100) {
          console.log(this);

          return this.point.realValue;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6zhj53vL/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load